# VBA Split data that fits criteria equally into 2 worksheets in another Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

Rows in **Workbook 1** that has column H, I, J or K filled up are ready for transfer.

I would like to copy and paste rows that are ready for transfer equally into 2 existing worksheets (Alex and IMHD) in **Workbook 2**.

Each worksheet in **Workbook 2** requires different information to be copied over from **Workbook 1**. I have figured out the 2 different sets of copy and paste codes.

However, I am unable to find the code that can split the data such that half executes the 1st copy and paste code (CopytoAlex), while the other half executes the other copy and paste code (CopytoIM).

Note: Feel free to make any clarifications. I have tried my best to explain.

```
Public Function CouriersTemplate()
Workbooks("Workbook 2.xlsb").Activate
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
Dim i As Integer, endrow As Integer, WB As Integer, RB As Integer, FI As Integer, CA As Integer, alexCounter As Integer, IMCounter As Integer
Dim alexDate As Date, deliveryDate As Date
Dim order As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

alexDate = courierDate("ALEX")
endrow = Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
alexCounter = Workbooks("Workbook 2.xlsb").Worksheets("ALEX").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
IMCounter = Workbooks("Workbook 2.xlsb").Worksheets("IMHD").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = endrow To 4 Step -1
 
 WB = Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(i, 8)
 RB = Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(i, 9)
 FI = Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(i, 10)
 CA = Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(i, 11)
 
 'Get delivery date
 deliveryDate = CDate(Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(i, 6).Value)
 
 If (RB >= 1 Or WB >= 1 Or FI >= 1 Or CA >= 1) And deliveryDate = alexDate Then
 Call CopytoAlex(i, alexCounter, order)
 alexCounter = alexCounter + 1
 
 Next (RB >= 1 Or WB >= 1 Or FI >= 1 Or CA >= 1) And deliveryDate = alexDate Then
 Call CopytoIM(i, IMCounter, order)
 IMCounter = IMCounter + 1
 
 End If
 
Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Many things could be improved in this code, but I'm just going to answer the immediate  question of how can I alternate output worksheets.  I'll try to preserve most of what you have here.

I want you to declare one more integer variable, let's call it AlexOrIM.  Set it to zero before you start your loop, `for i = endrow To 4 Step -1`.

Now let's rewrite that loop:

```
For i = endrow To 4 Step -1

 WB = Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(i, 8)
 RB = Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(i, 9)
 FI = Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(i, 10)
 CA = Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(i, 11)

 'Get delivery date
 deliveryDate = CDate(Workbooks("Workbook 1.xlsb").Worksheets("Masterlist").Cells(i, 6).Value)

 If (RB >= 1 Or WB >= 1 Or FI >= 1 Or CA >= 1) And deliveryDate = alexDate Then
    If (AlexOrIM mod 2) = 0 Then
        Call CopytoAlex(i, alexCounter, order)
        alexCounter = alexCounter + 1
    Else
        Call CopytoIM(i, IMCounter, order)
        IMCounter = IMCounter + 1
    End If
    AlexOrIM=AlexOrIM + 1
 END IF 
Next i
```

The AlexOrIM variable is tested for even value (write to alex) or odd value (write to IM) then incremented so next time through it writes to the other sheet.

Comment: Hi Chris! Thank you so much for your assistance! I understand the idea behind it and it works well!